# how can i not show webView when there's an error loading given url?

Tags: java, android, layout, webview, mobile-webkit

I have a webView which is given url and opens.

I don't open it when there is no network.

I have tried to load a non-existing server like: "localhost:999"

And my webView is opened with "android web error".

..

How can I check before I show the webView?

- I get server response 200

Meaning will close webView at once if

- no server answer after X sec
- errorCode isn't 200

I use today a simple code:

`mWebView.loadUrl(promotionUrl);`

Answer (score 0):

This will stop url from loading if no network is avaliable or the file doesn't exist.

```
 webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                public void     onReceivedError(WebView view, int     errorCode, String description, String     failingUrl) {

//create a html file  that will be loaded if no network is avaliable.

    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");

            //error message goes here.



}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will handle all errors and would give you response according to the errors.

```
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
{
Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
```